# Convert string to integer(s)

Tags: android, xml, string, integer

In my app i have just imported a string to this activity from another activity.
I need this string to be converted into 5 integers, the following:

```
        int counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5;
```

This is my code for receiving the string:

```
        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        number =  gotBasket.getString("lol");
```

The string is currently passed successfully, all i need is for it to be converted to integers.

Comment: I would suggest moving the "bonus question" into its own question, as they are unrelated.

Comment: Thanks to the guy answering my bonus question, it worked

Answer (score 1):

**Ad.1. Q**

```
Integer.parseInt(gotBasket.getString("lol"));
```

Watch out for the `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

**Ad.2. Q**

`ScrollView` per each column? You really want it that way?

Comment: Hi, what will the name of my integer be, when i use that code you wrote? Since i just tried it out, where i used the name of my string of the value i put into the TextViews in my app, but nothing showed up. And for the second question, yea i do - would you recommend otherwise? if so, why?

Comment: This method will try to parse the string that You pass to it. If the format of the string doesn't match it throws exception. This the pure java way for getting 'int' from 'String'. As for the second part I thought that You wanted to scroll the whole row of the table not each column separately. It's more tipical behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Integer.parseInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

EDIT: Or in the first activity attach the extra as an int, then in your new activity use [Bundle.getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yea, i read that on the android developer site too, i just wasn't exactly sure how to use it. Can you show me how i'm supposed to set it up with my string name?

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT, i'll see if i can figure it out.